# i am unable to log into ubuntu via the gui

Tags: 14.04, login, gui, user-management

when i log in via terminal i'm able to log into my account sudo up and do everything i need to. when i start the gui i'm only able to log in with root but not my user account. when do attempt to log in with my user account it acts like its going to log in then sends me back to the log in screen.

i have tried about everything i can with xauth file.from deleteing the the file adding the account to sudoers/adding it to root group and im still un able to log in. i'm at a lost here any help to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo chown -R user:user ~/`?  (replacing `user` with your username)

Comment: @anonymous2 the command is confusing.. which `user` to replace? just pointing so OP doesn't use the wrong command

Comment: The OP is supposed change both `user`'s with his/her username.

Comment: What happens if you enter `startx` command after logging into tty?

Comment: Can you log into the Guest account, and have a full GUI? I'll bet you can. Is there any possibility that a "friend" got access to your computer and wanted to prank you and put a "logout" command into one of the files that get accessed when you login... like .profile, .bashrc, etc? Or Startup Applications? Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

try to chown the .Xauthority file in your home folder

```
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.Xauthority
```

Let the system fill in the `UID`, `GID` and home directory.

This problem happens when you sudo instead of kdesudo/gksu/gksudo the file manager. hope this helps you.

Comment: You should also check for files/directories in/u der

Comment: You should also check for files/directories in/under `$HOME` that you don't own, by `sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -ls`, and `sudo chown` (think three times before using `chown -R`) if necessary.